# Debug estranho com Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, console, build

[image: Print de erro do debuger do Android Studio]

Reparem no print, o título(1) do erro possui mais detalhes que o corpo(2) do erro.
Não são todos os erros que aparecem dessa forma.
Tem como configurar o título para aparecer também junto com o corpo do erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Print do Android Studio apontando para o icone que alterna a visão do log de erro]

Fuçando aqui no Android Studio, achei uma opção de alternar o modo de visualizar o log com erro, assim facilitando a leitura e compreensão em casos onde mais detalhes aparece no título e não no corpo no modo de visualização padrão.